# how to access endpoint configuration in a custom NServiceBus profile handler

Tags: nservicebus, nservicebus5

I'm migrating code from NSBv4 to NSBv5 (5.2.12 to be exact) and I have a custom profile implementation:

```
public class MyProfileHandler : IHandleProfile<PerformanceCounters>
{
    public MyProfileHandler()
    {

    }

    public void ProfileActivated(BusConfiguration config)
    {
        // I need to do something based on endpoint configuration, e.g. endpoint name
        // this used to work in NSBv4:
        // var endpointName = Configure.EndpointName;
    }
}
```

How can I access endpoint configuration here?

I'm hosting this app using NServiceBus.Host (v6.0.0 if it matters) and this is where the `IHandleProfile<T>` interface comes from.

`BusConfiguration` is a configuration builder and it seems it's not possible to read anything useful from it. I tried to inject an instance of `Configure` to the constructor of my profile handler, but then it crashes - NSB needs the handler to have a parameterless constructor.

Implementing `IWantTheEndpointConfig` is not an option as well, as it is deprecated in v5 and it causes a compilation error. Its obsolete error message states:

> `IHandleProfile` is now passed an instance of `Configure`

(which would be perfect for my case), but this is not true as far as I can tell (there is no `Configure` passed to `ProfileActivated()` and I can't see how I can inject it).

Is my only option to reimplement the profile handler using a completely different approach, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

NServiceBus.Core has an issue how it sets the endpoint name (and unfortunately also the endpoint version) on the BusConfiguration. The set endpoint name is added to the settings dictionary too late. You can work around that issue by doing the following:

```
public class EndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint
{
    public void Customize(BusConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var customConfig = new EndpointConfiguration
        {
            EndpointName = "YourEndpointName",
        };

        configuration.EndpointName(customConfig.EndpointName);

        configuration.GetSettings().Set<EndpointConfiguration>(customConfig);
    }
}

public class EndpointConfiguration
{
    public string EndpointName { get; set; }
}
```

`BusConfiguration` is essentially a dictionary on steroids. If you want to get access to what has been set in the `BusConfiguration` in the profile handler you can do the following (i.ex. get the endpoint name):

```
public class MyProfileHandler : IHandleProfile<PerformanceCounters>
{
    public void ProfileActivated(BusConfiguration config)
    {
        var customConfig = config.GetSettings().Get<EndpointConfiguration>();
        var endpointName = customConfig.EndpointName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this throws a `KeyNotFoundException: The given key (EndpointName) was not present in the dictionary.`, regardless of whether I explicitly set the endpoint name using `configuration.EndpointName("MyEndpointName")` or not. I didn't mention it in my question, but I've already tried this approach. I've also found [this excellent post by Yogiraj Aradhye](http://aradhye.com/nservicebus-upgrade-from-v4-to-v5-part1/) which confirms it's not just me who can't get this to work.

Comment: Just checked. It is a bug in NServiceBus.Core. Do you only need to access the endpoint name? I can provide you a nasty workaround

Comment: Looks like a smart workaround, will give it a try later.

Comment: By the way, if this is a bug then is it already reported in their github repo?

Answer (score 0):

In the normal NServiceBus Host the interface offers only the one parameter, `BusConfiguration`. On Azure the interface offers two methods, where one actually has the `Configure` object.

Comment: Like I've already explained, `IWantTheEndPointConfig` is deprecated in NSB v5 (with error=true, so it doesn't even compile). The documentation you linked to is outdated (I've already reported this to Particular via their feedback form).

Comment: @JakubJanuszkiewicz Apologies, I misread it. I've just checked and on my side this is working, but it's weird you don't get these two methods obligatory since they're already in the standard interface. Perhaps upgrading to the newest version might help, if you're on an older version. It seems their docs are actually correct but something is different in your environment.

Comment: Where do you reference `IHandleProfile` from? Isn't it [this interface from NServiceBus.Host](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.Host/blob/develop/src/NServiceBus.Hosting.Profiles/IHandleProfile.cs)? It only has one method: `void ProfileActivated(BusConfiguration config);`.

Comment: I referenced this from the Azure Hosting project, which obviously doesn't make sense. I assumed it would be similar for the normal hosting. If you look in the ProfileManager you'll see that they indeed can't get anything else besides the BusConfiguration that you already have. I'm sorry, it seems like it's not possible in the normal NServiceBus.

Comment: Ok, it's clear now. I'm updating the question with hosting info, I didn't realize they provide such different APIs for different hosting scenarios. I appreciate your answer anyway.

Comment: @JakubJanuszkiewicz I'd suggest perhaps trying to get in touch with the guys from NServiceBus themselves. They normally do scout for StackOverflow, but it might just slip. You could raise it as a possible issue on their repositories, since it clearly doesn't follow the documentation!